# How to block users using Firebase as a backend?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Trying to allow users to block other users.  Block meaning:  posts from the blocked users will no longer show up in the feed.

Firebase Database:

```
/databaseRoot
    /userId1
       blockeduserId1 : true
       blockeduserId2 : true
   /posts
       childByAutoId1 :  //users data
       childByAutoId2 :  //users data
```

And I've set the rules in Firebase Database as follows:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {

    "posts": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },

      "users": {
        "$user_id":{
              ".read": "!root.child('blocked/'+$user_id+'/'+auth.uid+'/true').exists()",
                        ".write": true
        }
      }

  }
}
```

Problem: the code above just blocks the user that is blocking from reading any posts.  I.e. not just filtering out the blocked users.  Any pointers as to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).  You can't use rules to alter the result set of a query.  Either the query is able to get every matching child, or it get denied.  The rules will not evaluate the rules for each individual child to determine if it should be sent back to the client.

If you want to limit the results of a query, the query should have a filter that requests only the children that match some condition.